# Is there a memory leak in here?

Tags: objective-c

I'm newish to obj-c and I have some code that works, but I'm thinking I may be leaking memory as I have two `retain` statements and no `release` statements.

In both cases if I remove the `retain` I get a bad access error on `[btPairedDevices count]`

Am I doing this right or is there a better way?

```
//===================================================================================================
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        indexDeviceSearch = 0;
        // Grab a list of paired devices
        btPairedDevices = [IOBluetoothDevice pairedDevices];
        [btPairedDevices retain];
    }

    return self;
}


//===================================================================================================
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{       
    if(IOBluetoothValidateHardwareWithDescription(nil, nil) != kIOReturnSuccess)
    {
        [NSApp terminate:self];
    }

    NSLog(@"Application up an running");

    // Start our timer looking for paired phones
    timerDeviceSearch = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                         target:self
                                                       selector:@selector(timerDeviceSearchFired)
                                                       userInfo:nil
                                                        repeats:YES];
}


//===================================================================================================
- (void) timerDeviceSearchFired
{
    // Check out the device
    if (indexDeviceSearch < [btPairedDevices count])
    {
        IOBluetoothDevice *device = [btPairedDevices objectAtIndex:indexDeviceSearch];
        if ([device deviceClassMajor] == kBluetoothDeviceClassMajorPhone)
        {
            // Found a phone
            [self addNewDeviceIfAcceptable:device];
        }
    }

    // Update the list of devices just in case the use
    // paired something while we are running
    btPairedDevices = [IOBluetoothDevice pairedDevices];
    [btPairedDevices retain];

    // Inc the index
    indexDeviceSearch++;
    if (indexDeviceSearch >= [btPairedDevices count])
        indexDeviceSearch = 0;
}


//===========================================================================================================================
-(BOOL)addNewDeviceIfAcceptable:(IOBluetoothDevice*)device
{
    NSEnumerator *enumerator;
    IOBluetoothDevice *tmpDevice;
    const BluetoothDeviceAddress *newDeviceAddress = [device getAddress];

    // Allocate our array of monitored devices
    if(!btMonitoredDevices)
    {
        btMonitoredDevices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
        if(!btMonitoredDevices)
            return(FALSE);
        [btMonitoredDevices retain];
    }

    // Walk the devices in the array.
    enumerator = [btMonitoredDevices objectEnumerator];
    if(enumerator)
    {
        const BluetoothDeviceAddress* tempAddress = NULL;
        while((tmpDevice = [enumerator nextObject]))
        {
            tempAddress = [tmpDevice getAddress];
            if(memcmp(newDeviceAddress, tempAddress, sizeof(BluetoothDeviceAddress)) == 0 )
            {
                // Already have it.
                return(FALSE);
            }
        }
    }

    // Add new device to array
    NSLog(@"Monitoring new device: %@", [device nameOrAddress]);
    [btMonitoredDevices addObject:device];

    // Return that we haven't seen it.
    return(TRUE);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely be releasing both `btMonitoredDevices` and `btPairedDevices` in the `dealloc`. But it appears that this is your appDelegate so it matters little outside of correctness. I'd do it anyhow.

You shouldn't need the `retain` on `btMonitoredDevices` since you're calling `alloc` on it. So you already have a `retain` count of one on it. By calling `retain` on it you actually have a `retain` count of two.

So to sum up make sure you're releasing both in your `dealloc` and get rid of the `[btMonitedDecices retain];` and you should be good.